# Add more constraints to my controllers list method

Tags: grails

At the moment my controllers list method for the domain object Product is:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [productInstanceList: Product.list(params), productInstanceTotal: Product.count()]
}
```

I wish to add more constrains to this.  More specifically, I want to get the logged in user. This has a M:1 relationship to a domain entity called Manager.  Manager has a M:M relationship to domain entity Company.  Company has a 1:M relationship to Product. So I want to only return products that are from the appropriate company.

I start by doing:

```
def list(Integer max) {
// 1. Get logged in user. 
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser;
    // 2. Get corresponding manager.
    Manager mgr = user.getManager();
    // 3. Get corresponding companies
    companies = mgr.getCompanies();

    // 4. Get products for all companies - not sure smart way to get this.
    // 5. Need to add the products to the query
    ...
}
```

As can be seen I get stuck at steps 4, 5. Using raw SQL I would just to a join to represent to all the User's Manager's Companies' Products and then put this in as a `where` predicate and hit the product table.

But I want a grails / groovy solution.  I also need to keep the `params` in the query as this controller can also have `params` injected which are pass into the query,

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) to get all the products, like

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser;
    Manager mgr = user.getManager();
    companies = mgr.getCompanies();
    def productList = Product.createCriteria().list(params) {
        'in'("companies", companies)
    }
    [productInstanceList: productList, productInstanceTotal: productList.totalCount]
}
```